# A loop to find min values based on another column value, and merge into 1 dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
list ={'Security ID':['3e09ax', 'we9lkl', 'as42we','as5322', 'ot24tas', 'c34ci46a8'],
          'Industry':['Airplanes', 'Airplanes', 'Oil', 'Oil', 'Housing', 'Trucking'],
          'Amount outstanding':[33, 31, 39, 21, 29, 29]}
df = pd.DataFrame(list)
```

'''

**The end goal is to return rows for each Industry for the lowest (min) Amount Outstanding into a "Min Value" dataframe for a daily report**

essentially this but for each industry:

```
df[df['Amount outstanding'] == df['Amount outstanding'].min()]
```

First step  is get Unique Values for [Industry] into a list again and then generate a loop function that does this.

Not sure exactly how to this. This dataframe in reality is 100,000 rows with 30 industries that change daily.

Comment: `df.groupby('Industry')['Amount outstanding'].min()`?

Comment: This doesn't return the unique ID (first column). Ultimately this report needs to be the same dataframe structure but with min values of each industry.

Comment: `df[df['Amount outstanding'].eq(df.groupby('Industry')['Amount outstanding'].transform(min))]`

Comment: Can you please include your expected output? For example, the "Oil" industry has two security IDs. Which one (or both?) should be in the output?

Comment: @It_is_Chris this worked perfectly. thank you

Comment: @not_speshal the one with the lowest Amount outstanding value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['B']=df['Amount outstanding'] 
df.groupby('Industry', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.B.idxmin()])
```

this gives you a new dataframe only with min value in column Amount outstanding. If you want you can drop now the column 'B'

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you want `groupby` and `transform`:

```
output = df[df['Amount outstanding']==df.groupby('Industry')['Amount outstanding'].transform(min)]

>>> output

  Security ID   Industry  Amount outstanding
1      we9lkl  Airplanes                  31
3      as5322        Oil                  21
4     ot24tas    Housing                  29
5   c34ci46a8   Trucking                  29
```

Answer (score 1):

Concise and performant; `transform` and `apply` can be unsuitably slow especially for large dataframes.

```py
df.loc[df.groupby('Industry')['Amount outstanding'].idxmin()]
```

Broken down into parts:

```py
       df.groupby('Industry')                                # for each industry
                             ['Amount outstanding'].idxmin() # get index of minimum 'Amount outstanding' 
df.loc[                                                     ]# return those rows of the original dataframe
```

***Note well:*** make sure `dtype` of `'Amount outstanding'` column is a numeric; if it is `object`, it will be orders-of-magnitude slower than necessary.  I ran into something similar dealing with a `resample` on a dataframe of 1.9M rows, 30 cols; code that ran for minutes without completing finished in seconds after converting the columns from `object` to `float`.

Comment: Best and fastest. Drops duplicates, relatively easy to understand even without any explanation text (!) and reuse. Imagine how many upvotes with a bit of explanation.

Comment: @DrWhat thanks for the kind note. Edited & (hopefully) improved.